# How to call from jsp to java function

Tags: java, function, jsp, call

I have written jsp code as,

```
<form:form method="post" action="/getnextinvoice">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" onclick="getnextinvoice()" value="New" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Here form "action" get calls well from java page function.
But i want to call "onclick" property to call the java function.
My java function is as,

```
@RequestMapping("/getnextinvoice")
    public String getnextinvoice(@ModelAttribute usercreation user) {

     String invoice = iDaoImpl.getInvoiceNo();

     System.out.println(invoice);
     return "redirect:/Invoice";
    }
```

So Please help me ,and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial here at how views are mapped against actions calls.

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/)